# Server re-hosted, needs to update new IP address in DNS

Tags: dns, apache-http-server, ip, centos-7, domain-name

Our `Centos7` server was relocated to a new building and the IP address changed. Now how do I configure the server so all traffic gets routed to the new IP address?The domain name is still the same. The server runs Apache Web Server.

Comment: If this server only runs Apace, it's not the one you need to configure. You need to re-configure the DNS server so that the name points to the new IP.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a new A or AAAA record, either with your DNS registrar, or whoever handles your DNS server internally. You don't need to change anything on the server itself

Comment: configured dns and that fixed the problem.